# Codeacademy "Learn Java." Compilation: Creating Executables issue

Tags: java, compilation

it's my first time here and I'm currently learning Java using Codeacademy. I reached compiling Java code and for some reason, I'm not getting the compilation correctly even though I'm following the instructions and everything. You compile by writing "javac FileName.java" and that's exactly what I'm doing. I checked for spelling mistakes or capitalization mistakes and found none. I tried resetting Codeacademy a few times, still getting the same issue. Please see below and inform me what is wrong because Codeacademy's "hint" also turned out useless.
[image]

Comment: You have to press [enter] after the command.

Comment: But if you >have< pressed [enter] and it still didn't work ... contact the CodeAcademy support team.